# I want to use the uuid generator but I have an error

Tags: javascript, html, random, node-modules, uuid

**I import this on my JS file :**

import {v4 as uuidv4} from './uuid';

**and here is the error : **

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

need help pls

Comment: change './uuid' to 'uuid' to resolve from node_modules (this way it looks for relative path)

Comment: I do that : import {v4 as uuidv4} from "./node_modules/uuid"; but the error is the same

Comment: Why not just use built-in  `crypto.randomUUID()` method.

Comment: yes no big deal i will use that instead thanks @Anilkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your imports because it looks like you're not doing it right.

Create a UUID (ES6 module syntax):

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

... or using CommonJS syntax:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'
```

You can read more about it in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid?activeTab=readme).

Comment: when I try on a windows pc it works but not on my ubuntu it's weird,
thank you for your help